# accessing nested dictionary json in swift 5

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

and I hope that you good job in every matter , actually I want to access name of countries in countryId (nested dictionary) these Jason format and I test different ways and  but unfortunately I don't understand the solution, could you help me to solve it?
this is my json :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "606836792ed79e4194e98848",
        "title": "berlin",
        "countryId": {
            "_id": "6068366e2ed79e4194e98847",
            "name": "germany",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "60505f8c8acc922dc46a60eb",
        "title": "ezmir",
        "countryId": {
            "_id": "60505f808acc922dc46a60ea",
            "name": "turkey",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "606836942ed79e4194e9884b",
        "title": "karaj",
        "countryId": {
            "_id": "606836832ed79e4194e98849",
            "name": "iran",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "60696c7b1c7a4937a817c463",
        "title": "new york",
        "countryId": {
            "_id": "60696c461c7a4937a817c462",
            "name": "usa",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "60696c0d1c7a4937a817c461",
        "title": "stanbol",
        "countryId": {
            "_id": "60505f808acc922dc46a60ea",
            "name": "turkey",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6068368d2ed79e4194e9884a",
        "title": "tabriz",
        "countryId": {
            "_id": "606836832ed79e4194e98849",
            "name": "iran",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

and this I also where I want to solve it in my code :

```
  
        func fetchingcityInformation()  {
           let url = "http://192.168.1.199:2581/api/citys"
           
           do {
               let data =  try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)
               let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
            guard let array = json as? [Any] else { return }
            print("the json file is : \(array)")
            print(" country is folan : \(array[2]) ")
            for users in array {
                guard let usersDict = users as? [String: Any] else { return }
             
             guard let names = usersDict["countryId"] as? [String : String] else { return }
                print(" userDict is : \(String(describing: usersDict["countryId"])) ")
             print("the country id is : \(names)")
             // inja boodi
             
             //guard var countryId = user as? [String: Any] else { return }
             
             //countryArray = names
                 if countryPressed == countryArray["name"] {
                     guard (usersDict["title"] as? String) != nil else {
                         return
                     }
                     cityslbl.append(title!)
                 }
             
            }
```

Comment: Please edit your post post to include code and not pictures of code, which is bad for search, screen readers, copy and paste, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using QuickType.io (https://app.quicktype.io) for this kind of thing. It gives this for the JSON structure:

```
struct WelcomeElement: Codable {
    let id, title: String
    let countryID: CountryID
    let v: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case title
        case countryID = "countryId"
        case v = "__v"
    }
}

// MARK: - CountryID
struct CountryID: Codable {
    let id, name: String
    let v: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case name
        case v = "__v"
    }
}
```

And then decoding and accessing the internal elements is easy:

```
do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode([WelcomeElement].self, from: jsonData)
    root.forEach { (element) in
        print(element.countryID)
        print(element.title)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

You *could* continue to just use the untyped `[String:Any]` dictionaries, but it's not friendly and quite error prone:

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers)

    guard let array = json as? [[String:Any]] else {
        assertionFailure("Bad cast")
        return
    }
    
    array.forEach { (element) in
        print(element["title"] ?? "unknown")
        if let countryId = element["countryId"] as? [String:String] {
            print(countryId["name"] ?? "unknown")
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Using `Codable` and `JSONDecoder` is definitely the way to go. `CodingKeys` is not strictly necessary, `__v` and `_id` are valid identifiers as is, if not very Swifty.

Comment: Very true. Just using the direct, unedited output from QuickType.

Comment: yeah, great solution thank you brother , finally I had the result that I want, again thanks and I hope that every code that you stuck in as soon as you answered my question speedly you get answer and I hope these for every programmers.

Comment: Wow -- what a nice sentiment! Glad I could help.

Comment: thanks a lot , your eyes see beautiful , good job